# How to insert class into stl map on class initialization

Tags: c++, class, dictionary, constructor, initialization

SOLVED: http://pastebin.com/seEaALZh

I was trying to create simple items system, where i can get item information by its id. I cant use array, because items ids are lets say random. I want to use declared items as variables and i want to quickly find any item info by its id. The only way i found is stl map.

So I have this simple code:

1. main.h

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <map>

   enum
   {
       weapon,
       ammo
   };

   class c_items
   {
       bool operator()(const c_items& l, const c_items& r) const
       {
           return (l.id < r.id);
       }
   public:
       c_items(void){};
       c_items(int id, char name[], int type);
       char *name;
       int type;
       int id;
   };

   extern std::map<int,c_items> Stuff;

   c_items::c_items(int id, char name[], int type) : id(id), type(type), name(name)
   {
       Stuff[id] = c_items(id, name, type);
   }

   const c_items
       brass_knuckles          (546, "Brass knuckles", weapon),
       golf_club               (2165, "Gold club", weapon);
   ```
2. main.cpp

   ```
   #include "main.h"

   std::map<int,c_items> Stuff;

   using namespace std;

   int main()
   {
       // cout << Stuff[2165].name.data();
       return 1;
   }
   ```

And for some reason program crashes. How to correctly insert class data into map on class initialization?

Comment: your code is recursive ? when you create an item it will create an item etc.... crash!!!

Comment: thanks alex for spotting this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is order of initialization.  The static constructors for `brass_knuckles` and `golf_club` run first, before the static constructor for `Stuff`, so they attempt to insert into a map that is not yet constructed.

In addition, you NEVER want variable DEFINITIONS in a header file, since if you include the header file in multiple source files, you end up with multiple definitions, which will at best cause a link failure.  So you should move the DEFINITIONS out of the .h file and into the .cpp file.  Putting them AFTER the definition of `Stuff` will fix the order of initialization problem.

You can have a DECLARATION of the variables in the header file if you want to use them in other compilation units:

```
extern const c_items brass_knuckles, golf_club;
```

Comment: And thanks for you, i changed variables order, added externs of items, change Stuff[id] = c_items(...) to Stuff[id] = *this; and problem solved :) Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot put c_item in Stuff like that
instead

```
 std::map<int,c_items> Stuff = { {item1.id, item1}, {item2.id, item2}};
```

but you also need to all the recommendation made by @Chris Dodd

so

```
c_items::c_items(int id, char name[], int type) : id(id), type(type), name(name)
{}

extern const c_items  brass_knuckles,      golf_club;
```

and in the main.cpp

```
 const c_items  brass_knuckles = {546, "Brass knuckles", weapon);
    const c_items golf_club = (2165, "Gold club", weapon);
    std::map<int,c_items> Stuff = { {brass_knuckles.id, brass_knuckles}, etc....};
```